# disable CUDA when using dlib library as a dependency in my project

Tags: cmake, dlib

as suggested in the `cmake` files I import `dlib` in my project using:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(dlib
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
    GIT_TAG        v19.18
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(dlib)
```

I don't want dlib to use CUDA. How do I disable it?

Comment: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/569

Answer (score 0):

I can not disable cuda for dlib. because if I disable then another error happened. instead of disabling I applied the following approach this Is working in my PC:

1. Create a new virtual environment
2. `pip --no-cache-dir install cmake`
3. `pip --no-cache-dir install -v --install-option="--no" --install-option="DLIB_USE_CUDA" dlib`

The line number 3 is the most important it install dlib without cuda support

4. `pip --no-cache-dir install face-recognition`

I am working face recognition project. and project is working now without error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing as recommended in 3. but I receive the following message:

```
(venv) PS C:\users\dave\desktop\file> pip --no-cache-dir install -v --install- option="--no" --install-option="DLIB_USE_CUDA" dlib

Usage:
pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --install-option
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in `pip --install-option`, it has been depreciated.

```
sudo pip install -v --config-settings ="--no" --config-settings ="DLIB_USE_CUDA" dlib
```

Please use this command instead of the old one, its working for me atm.